# JRE/fontconfig default exclusion ranges. Unable to display certain Unicode characters

Tags: java, fontconfig

I tried to display the Unicode character `\u1e41` (m with a dot) in a `JLabel`, the result was a little square indicating that the character can't be displayed. In other default windows apps (notepad etc.), this is possible. I found that the character is in the first exclusion range in all of my JRE installations (file `fontconfig.properties.src`):

```
exclusion.alphabetic=0700-1e9f,1f00-20ab,20ad-f8ff
```

I changed this line to:
    exclusion.alphabetic=0700-1e40,1e42-1e9f,1f00-20ab,20ad-f8ff

and renamed the file `fontconfig.properties.src` to `fontconfig.properties`. This enabled my application to display this character. Now, I would like to know:

1. Why is this range excluded per default?
2. Is there any way I can display this character without changing the JRE or can I change this setting programmatically?
3. If 2 is not possible, is it dangerous to set the fontconfig file like I did? I ask this, because I think the fontconfig file may contain settings that have side effects for my applications. Or does the file always contains the JRE's default settings (so it wouldn't have any effect if I rename the file without modifications)?

For reference...

- Machine: Windows 7 64-Bit
- JRE versions: 1.7.0, 1.6.0_25, 1.6.0._25 / All 32-Bit